# How to replace categorical variables with its numerical representations for further calculating their correlations?

Tags: python, dataframe, transform, numeric, categorical-data

1. I have a data-frame with information about different users (ID) with many duplicated categorical variables (photo and hash-tags) and its corresponding numbers of interactions (likes and comments). How i can replace categorical variables with its numeric transformations?

For example:

```
id    photo_type    likes comments   hash-tags

1     nature          2      1        [#nature, #shooting, #photography]

2     art             4      5        [#shooting, #photography]

3     art             1      3        [#art, #shooting]

4     fashion         3      0        [#beauty, #photography]

5     fashion         2      0        [#shooting, #photography]
```

I expect to get:

```
id    photo_type    likes  hash-tags

1     0 0 1           2      ?

2     0 1 0           4      ?

3     0 1 0           1      ?

4     1 0 0           3      ?

5     1 0 0           2      ?
```

I have tried one-hot (get_dummies(photo_type)), but it adds more numerical columns to my dataframe, what i want is to replace the categorical column with its numerical transformation for photo type.

Comment: Please ask one question in one post. You can edit this post to remove the second question and ask it separately

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

I think what you are looking for is one hot encoding.

```py
df
>>>index Color
0        Red  
1        Blue
2        Green
3        Red

pd.get_dummies(df.Color)
df
>>>index Red  Blue  Green
0        1    0     0 
1        0    1     0
2        0    0     1
3        1    0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the replace method with a dict like that:

```
df.replace({'nature':'0 0 1', 'art': '0 1 0', 'fashion': '1 0 0'})
```